# How can i use localStorage on my React app?

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, frontend

I am fetching data from an API, i would like to use localStorage for one hour, i need to fetch data after every hour.

- My API looks like :

  ```
  {
    "name": "My Name",
    "logo": "https://media.img.jpeg",
    "note": "14,5",
    "students": 3720,
    "url": "https://url.students/alain"
  }
  ```
- Here is my code, https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-cloud-qzmef

Comment: Instead of local storage, you could consider client-side caching for 1 hour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is to save the necessary data with a timestamp. And check whether the date has been expired.

```js
loadData = () => {
    // Check whether data exists in localStorage and has been
    // saved less than an hour ago
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('brand'));
    if (data && (new Date().getTime() - data.created <= 3600)) {
        this.setState({
            note: data.brand.note,
            logo: data.brand.logo,
            name: data.brand.name,
        });

        return;
    }

    // Otherwise perform request
    axios.get('https://myAPI.url').then(res => {
        const brand = res.data;

        // and save data in local storage with the current timestamp
        localStorage.setItem(
            'brand',
            JSON.stringify({
                created: new Date().getTime(),
                brand,
            }),
        );

        this.setState({
            note: brand.note,
            logo: brand.logo,
            name: brand.name,
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    // Save To localStorage
    const data = {
            "name": "My Name",
            "logo": "https://media.img.jpeg",
            "note": "14,5",
            "students": 3720,
            "url": "https://url.students/alain"
    }
    localStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(data))


    // To Get data from localstorage 
    const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('key'));
    console.log(data);


    // To Remove Data
    localStorage.removeItem('key');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of saving these items to your localStorage, I recommend to store them in the redux store instead. 
If you're not using Redux: https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/quick-start